# SharePoint HTTPModule to redirect

Tags: http-module

Thanks for your help.
I have one requirement where I need to redirect users based on group membership when the user first browses to the site. I have been trying to implement a httpmodule and handling the postauthenticaterequest event. However, this event keeps on firing at every page browse resulting in the user being redirected continuously. So, to handle that I put in cookies. However, still I am having issues. Can someone please guide me the way to implement this for sharepoint?

Requirement is to redirect user based on group permission to 2 different pages; they are not access controlled - just the default landing page is different based on group membership.

THanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You're best handling this in a custom control on the masterpage - HTTPModules will fire on every single request, and potentially kill performance if you're not careful.

Answer (score 0):

I agrree with James' reply - http modules can be dangerous if you're nor careful. But if you add a control to the masterpage it will run for every page that uses that masterpage, which may as well get you in a continuous redirect loop.

I'd sugest using a simple WebPart that you can add to your homepage which sends users to page A or page B depending on their group membership.